# FFmpeg speeding up audio without losing quality or making high-pitched sounds

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, pitch

Trying to speed up audio makes all the t's and s's really sharp. I have no idea how to fix it. How do I dull them down?

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter:a "atempo=2.0" -vn output.mp3
```

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1118826

Comment: Also https://superuser.com/a/1132229/ & https://superuser.com/a/611927/